# Adding CSS to Blazor WebAssembly views

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Im doing a web project in  Blazor WebAssembly and i want to add a specific CSS file to one of my .razor files but i have no idea on earth how to do it.

The project looks like this.
[image]

Any one who knows how i add a CSS for ListProducts.razor ?

Comment: Is CSS isolation what you're after?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want css file to be specific to one razor file then create css file in same directory with {razor_file_name}.razor.css.

For you case ListProducts.razor.css

info: [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for thank you!

Comment: I can't understand why this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo:

My wwwroot folder:

[image]

.razor file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap1.min.css" />
@code {
   ...
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: is that for a individual blazor file ?

Comment: Yes,I add it to `FetchData.razor` to test.

Answer (score -1):

You should already have a premade `app.css` file located in `wwwroot/css/app.css`

Add the CSS for your entire app there

Comment: I want a css that is specific for one razor file. Not everything.